# can't locate element with dynamic id

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am creating some tests with Selenium for a project that I am working for. For some reason I can't locate an element with its id, class, xpath etc. Maybe I am doing something wrong. After I login into the application the page looks like this:

[After I login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uic9R.png)

If you see the 3 tabs: Favorites, My project, All projects they all have Ids 12, 13, 14 respectively. When I click the button 'Add project' and click 'Create' a new project is added and this project under 'My projects'. So my purpose is after creating this project to click on 'My projects' button and then click on the name of the new project and edit it so I can make some modifications and move on with my test. The problem is that when I try to click on the 'My projects' button I can't and it says that this property cannot be clicked. After I add the new project the Ids of the three aforementioned buttons also change. So the 'Favorites' has now Id=15, 'My projects' has Id=16 and 'All projects' has Id=17. Can anyone help and let me know what is the right way to locate an element like this? I have tried different things but nothing works so far. Below is the code in my test and a screenshot with the element inspect. Thank you in advance, any help would be much appreciated.

```
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).SendKeys("admin");
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Login'])[3]/following::table[1]")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("admin");
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Password'])[1]/following::input[2]")).Click();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("addproject-button")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("Name")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("Name")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("Name")).SendKeys("ProjectX");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("Comments")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("Comments")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("Comments")).SendKeys("the project");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("addproject")).Click();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        //****************** THIS IS WHERE MY TEST FAILS-IT CAN'T LOCATE THE ELEMENT BY.ID*****************
          driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='ui-state-default ui-corner-top']/a[contains(.,'My projects')]")).Click();
        //driver.FindElement(By.Id("ui-id-16")).Click();
        //driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a.ui-tabs-anchor[id='ui-id-16']")).Click();

//driver.FindElement(By.Id("ProjectListTable")).FindElement(By.Id("project-list-tabs-content")).Click();//FindElement(By.ClassName("ui-state-default.ui-corner-top.ui-tabs-active.ui-state-active")).Click();
        //driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ui-tabs-anchor")).Click();
```

[My project button after I create the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HiJ5.png)

Comment: Please mention what is the error that you are getting and on which line you are getting that.

Comment: Kindly share snippet of HTML.

Comment: Hi the error I get is the following: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: Element <a href="#my" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-13">...</a> is not clickable at point (176, 193). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal-body">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.96)
  
and the line it occurs is the first line after the the title 'THIS IS WHERE M TEST FAILS'  and the line is driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='ui-state-default ui-corner-top']/a[contains(.,'My projects')]")).Click();

Comment: The button I want to click on is the 'My projects' button but the test seems it can't locate the element. <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="my" aria-labelledby="ui-id-16" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true"><a href="#my" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-16">My projects</a></li>.  <a href="#my" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-16">My projects</a>

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use two

```
IList<IWebElement>
```

One with Project names, second with elements, which you can click. Then, you can iterate on the first list, to get number of the row, where is needed project. Then click on this project, by using second list.